# How to find five first maximum indices of each column in a matrix?

Tags: scala, matrix, apache-spark

This is my matrix and i want to extract five first maximum indices of each column in Spark and Scala using Breeze:

```
indices

  0         0.23 0.20 0.10 0.92 0.33 0.42
  1         0.10 0.43 0.23 0.15 0.22 0.12
  2         0.20 0.13 0.25 0.85 0.02 0.32
  3         0.43 0.65 0.23 0.45 0.10 0.33
  4         0.31 0.87 0.45 0.63 0.28 0.16
  5         0.12 0.84 0.33 0.45 0.56 0.83
  6         0.40 0.22 0.12 0.87 0.35 0.78
           ...
```

(Note : indices are not in matrix , just for showing the problem better )

and expected output is :

```
3 4 4 0 5 5
6 5 5 6 6 6
4 3 2 2 0 0
0 1 1 4 4 3
2 6 3 3 1 2
```

i've tried :

```
  for (i <- 0 until I) {
      val T = argmax(matrix(::, i))
      results(::,i) := T
    }
```

but it return only first maximum index .

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Please supply exact scala type of your collection

Comment: I don't see how your output and input relate. Please explain in more detail

Comment: argmax() return maximum index not maximum value, i want something like this but it could return five first maximum indices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you can use a little bit of the functional programming that Scala can offer to you, Breeze is very useful for working like in matlab, but argmax() give only the index that has the bigger number in a vector. Of course you can work like this, and then get the second bigger, then the third ...,But here you have my propose,I think that this will also help your Spark code in order to parallelize and work with larger matrix, please read the comments for an explanation, also feel free to make changes in order to get maximum capabilities using Spark:

```
package breeze

import breeze.linalg.{DenseMatrix }

/**
 * Created by anquegi on 24/05/15.
 */
object TestMatrix extends App {

  //This is a DenseMatrix from Breeze,
  // I suppose that you have something like this

  val m = DenseMatrix(
    (0.23, 0.20, 0.10, 0.92, 0.33, 0.42),
    (0.10, 0.43, 0.23, 0.15, 0.22, 0.12),
    (0.20, 0.13, 0.25, 0.85, 0.02, 0.32),
    (0.43, 0.65, 0.23, 0.45, 0.10, 0.33),
    (0.31, 0.87, 0.45, 0.63, 0.28, 0.16),
    (0.12, 0.84, 0.33, 0.45, 0.56, 0.83),
    (0.40, 0.22, 0.12, 0.87, 0.35, 0.78))

  // Let's work in a mix functional style and iterator working with columns
  // look at this example

  val a = m(::, 0) // get the firts column
    .toArray // pass to scala array for functional usage, you can use then to List
    .zipWithIndex // now you have and array like [(value0,0),(value1,1) ... (valuen,n)]
    .sortWith((x, y) => x._1 > y._1) // sort by bigger number
    .take(5) // get only 5 first numbers
    .map(x => x._2) // finally get the indexes

  //now we have to loop for each colum
  // prepare the matrix and get the Vector(indexes,Array[Int],Array[Int])

  val listsOfIndexes = for (i <- Range(0, m.cols))
    yield m(::, i).toArray
    .zipWithIndex
    .sortWith((x, y) => x._1 > y._1)
    .take(5)
    .map(x => x._2)

  //finally conver to a DenseMatrix

  val mIndex = DenseMatrix(listsOfIndexes.map(_.toArray): _*).t

  println(mIndex)

}
```

and the result:

```
[info] Running breeze.TestMatrix 
3  4  4  0  5  5  
6  5  5  6  6  6  
4  3  2  2  0  0  
0  1  1  4  4  3  
2  6  3  3  1  2  
[success] Total time: 5 s, completed 24/05/2015 16:59:43
```

> 